# SQLAlchemy -- group and count unique with as few queries as possible

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a table of `measurement`s, each with a `type` column.  I would like to group the measurements by their type.

Using the ORM, I can think of doing `types = [m.type for m in session.query(Measurement).distinct(Measurement.type).all()]` and then looping over `types` and doing a `filter_by(type==type)`, but I feel that this will thrash the db.

I'm using postgres 10.  Is it possible that I can thrash the db, and it will cache the intermediate results?  If not, should I use something like redis to do the caching myself?  The best option IMO is to optimize the queries done through SQLalchemy, but I do not know how to do so.

My desired output (format not necessarily matching) is something like:

```
types = ['type 1', 'type 2', 'type 3', ...]
counts = [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? please add desired output

Comment: I added an example to the bottom of the post.